# Get value of column 1 based on other column 2 value

Tags: powershell

```
 $var=(Get-EC2Instance -Credential $Creds).Instances | select InstanceID, @{Name="Servername";Expression={$_.tags | where key -eq "Name" | select Value -expand Value}}
```

Now $var holds the value like below

```
InstanceID     | Servername
---------      |----------
Inst1          | A
Inst2          | B
Inst3          | C
```

How do I return InstanceID based on server name

Comment: Edit the question and show how you populate the variable.

Comment: Here is an example of how I populate the variable $var=(Get-EC2Instance -Credential $Creds).Instances | select InstanceID, @{Name="Servername";Expression={$_.tags | where key -eq "Name" | select Value -expand Value}}

Comment: @ManikandanSoubramaniane - please, put the added info in your Question & wrap it in code formatting so that it can be easily read - and easily found. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, just made the changes

Comment: @ManikandanSoubramaniane - thank you! [*grin*] ///// one you have that info in a collection, you can use `$Collection.Where({$_.ServerName -eq $WantedName}).InstanceID` to get the IID that goes with a given server name.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Lee_Daily's comment above, but it should also work.

```
$var = (Get-EC2Instance -Credential $Creds).Instances | select InstanceID, @{ Name="Servername"; Expression = {$_.tags | where key -eq "Name" | select Value -expand Value} }

function GetInstanceId($serverData, $serverName) {
    $var | Where-Object {
        $_.ServerName -eq $serverName
    }
}

$instanceData = GetInstanceId -serverData $var -serverName 'A'

Write-Host $instanceData.InstanceID
```